# Making (or finding) a realistic image of the sun as seen from space

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, image, panoramic

I'm making a game set on the moon, and I'm currently making the background in blender 2.8. I'm using cycles, which means I can't make a believable-looking sun (cycles doesn't have bloom, and I'm not sure how to apply post-processing to an equirectangular image).

My solution is to render my scene with an image of the sun in place of a real object, but searching "image of sun" in google just has darkened, easy to observe "scientific" images, not the blinding light I'm looking for. I'm thinking I should render an image in blender using the eevee engine (which has bloom), but I want it to look realistic--not too perfect--like a camera took it.

The problem is, I don't know the first place to start, or of a better method that might exist for what I'm trying to do.

**TLDR:** I need help creating an image of the sun in blender, such as what post-processing shader I should use, what renderer, etc. A pointer to a pre-existing image of the sun would also be incredibly useful.

**EDIT:** I figure it probably would be useful to provide an example of what I'm thinking of: [image: Picture of the sun from a satellite]
Note the rays, caused by imperfections in the camera. I'm looking for a picture like this, minus the earth and spacecraft (which I can't find for the life of me on google). I've tried looking at NASA's catalog, but they only have "useful" images of the sun: [image: Example of what I'm NOT looking for]
Not realistic.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174460/how-do-i-texture-paint-with-glow/174463#174463 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207790/making-ores-glow-minecraft/207801#207801

Comment: NASA and https://www.solarsystemscope.com/ is a great resorce for all things space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Cycles equivalent to Eevee's Bloom Option?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140151/is-there-a-cycles-equivalent-to-eevees-bloom-option)